# Why updating master-detail GridView content throws FormatException while detail grid still open?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress

**Background**

I have master-detail gridview MVC 5 project using EF 6 Database First & DevExpress 15.2. The project structure given below (feel free to reproduce):

Model (ProjectModel.cs)

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    // EF data context
    public class ProjectContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectContext : base("DatabaseConnection") 
        { 
        }
        public DbSet<Receipt> Receipts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SoldList> SoldLists { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("Receipt")]
    public class Receipt
    {
        [Key]
        public int ReceiptID { get; set; }
        public String SessionID { get; set; }
        public String MemberID { get; set; }
        public String MemberName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReceiptDate { get; set; }
        public String TransID { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal RemainingCredit { get; set; }
        public bool? UseRemainingCredit { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("SoldList")]
    public class SoldList
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public String SessionID { get; set; }
        public String MemberID { get; set; }
        public int TransID { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPrice{ get; set; }
        public bool? UseRemainingCredit { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (MasterController.cs)

```
namespace Project.Controllers
{
    public class MasterController : Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Transaction()
        {
            using (var DB = new ProjectContext())
            {
                var model = (from record in DB.Receipts select record).ToList();
                return View(model);
            }
        }

    // master grid partial view
    public PartialViewResult PVTransaction()
    {
        using (var DB = new ProjectContext())
        {
            var model = (from record in DB.Receipts select record).ToList();
            return PartialView("_MasterTrans", model);
        }
    }

    // detail grid partial view
    public PartialViewResult PVDetails(String sessionID, String memberID, String transID)
    {
        ViewData["TransID"] = transID;
        // edit: adding forgotten IDisposable context declaration 
        using (var DB = new ProjectContext())
        {
            var model = (from list in DB.SoldLists where list.TransID == transID && list.MemberID == memberID && list.SessionID == sessionID select list).ToList();
            return PartialView("_DetailTrans", model);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public PartialViewResult EditTrans(Receipt item)
    {
        using (var DB = new ProjectContext())
        {
            var model = (from record in DB.Receipts select record).ToList();
            try
            {
                var match = DB.Receipts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ReceiptID == item.ReceiptID);
                if (match != null)
                {
                    var sum = DB.SoldLists.Where(x => x.TransID == match.TransID).Select(x => x.TotalPrice).Sum();
                    var useRemaining = DB.SoldLists.Where(x => x.TransID == match.TransID).Select(x => x.UseRemainingCredit).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (item.TotalPrice - match.RemainingCredit != sum && (useRemaining == null || useRemaining == false))
                    {
                        // other unrelated code
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        match.SessionID = item.SessionID;
                        match.MemberID = item.MemberID;
                        // other data update definitions

                        this.UpdateModel(match);
                        DB.SaveChanges();
                        ViewBag.Success = "Selected data edited successfully.";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Problem on editing with error message: \'" + e.Message + "\'";
            }
            return PartialView("_MasterTrans", model);
        }
    }
}
```

View (Transaction.cshtml)

```
@using Project.Models
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onMasterInit(s, e) {
        MasterGrid.PerformCallback();
    }
    function endMasterCallback(s, e) {
        if (s.cpMasterMsg) {
            alert(s.cpMasterMsg);
            delete s.cpMasterMsg;
            MasterGrid.Refresh();
        }
        else if (s.cpErrorMsg) {
            alert(s.cpErrorMsg);
            delete s.cpErrorMsg;
            MasterGrid.Refresh();
        }
    }
</script>
<label class="description">Transaction List</label>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    Html.RenderAction("PVTransaction", "Master");
}
```

Partial View (_MasterTrans.cshtml)

```
@using Project.Models
@{
    GridViewExtension grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "MasterGrid";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Master", Action = "PVTransaction" };
        settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowEditButton = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowUpdateButton = true;
        settings.CommandColumn.ShowCancelButton = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowFocusedRow = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowSelectByRowClick = true;
        settings.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;
        settings.SettingsContextMenu.Enabled = true;
        settings.SettingsContextMenu.EnableRowMenu = DefaultBoolean.True;
        settings.SettingsContextMenu.EnableColumnMenu = DefaultBoolean.True;
        settings.SettingsEditing.Mode = GridViewEditingMode.PopupEditForm;
        settings.SettingsEditing.UpdateRowRouteValues = new { Controller = "Master", Action = "EditTrans" };

        settings.SettingsText.ConfirmDelete = "Remove selected data?";
        settings.SettingsText.ContextMenuExpandDetailRow = "Show Details";
        settings.SettingsText.ContextMenuCollapseDetailRow = "Hide Details";
        settings.ClientSideEvents.Init = "onMasterInit";
        settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "endMasterCallback";
        settings.CustomJSProperties = (s, e) =>
        {
            if (ViewBag.Success != null)
            {
                e.Properties["cpMasterMsg"] = ViewBag.Success.ToString();
                e.Properties["cpErrorMsg"] = ViewBag.Error.ToString();
            }
        };

        // begin detail gridview
        settings.SettingsDetail.AllowOnlyOneMasterRowExpanded = false;
        settings.SettingsDetail.ShowDetailButtons = true;
        settings.SettingsDetail.ShowDetailRow = true;
        settings.SetDetailRowTemplateContent(content =>
        {
            ViewContext.Writer.Write(@"<p style=""font-size:14px; text-decoration:underline"">Transaction Detail of " + DataBinder.Eval(content.DataItem, "MemberName") + " at " + String.Format("{0:yyyy/MMMM/dd}", DataBinder.Eval(content.DataItem, "ReceiptDate")) + ", Session ID: " + DataBinder.Eval(content.DataItem, "SessionID") + "</p>");

            // this line throws FormatException on editing master grid while detail grid still open
            Html.RenderAction("PVDetails", "Master", new { sessionID = DataBinder.Eval(content.DataItem, "SessionID"), memberID = DataBinder.Eval(content.DataItem, "MemberID"), transID = DataBinder.Eval(content.DataItem, "TransID")}); 
        });

        // end of detail gridview

        settings.KeyFieldName = "ReceiptID";
        settings.Columns.Add(column => 
        {
            column.FieldName = "ReceiptID";
            column.Caption = "Receipt ID";
        }
        // other columns with similar construction
        // including SessionID, MemberID, MemberName, ReceiptDate, TransID columns
    }
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

Partial View (_DetailTrans.cshtml)

```
@using Project.Models
@{
    GridViewExtension grid = Html.DevExpress().GridView(settings =>
    {
        settings.Name = "DetailGrid" + ViewData["TransID"]; // using transaction ID column from master grid to generate unique detail grid name
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Master", Action = "PVDetails" };

        settings.SettingsDetail.MasterGridName = "MasterGrid";
        settings.KeyFieldName = "ItemID";

        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.Name = "ItemID";
            column.Caption = "Item ID";
        });
        // other columns with similar construction
    }
}
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

**Problem Statement**

Master gridview provides editing transaction data and detail gridview shows item list by values from master grid. When user clicking `Edit` button, a popup edit window shows up providing editable data.

TransID property contains random 40-digit hexadecimal ensuring valid transactions.

All edit operations work fine if detail grid was hidden, but if a user trying to edit & update master grid content when a detail gridview still open (with collapse sign), `FormatException` was thrown (see details).

Despite view throwing exception, the edited data saved successfully but it will redirect to custom error page. I searched by keyword given inside additional information with no results.

**Exception Details**

```
An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Web.dll was caught.

HResult: -2146233033
Source: DevExpress.Web.v15.2
Additional information: Unexpected 'O' at 0
Stack Trace (simplified):

   at DevExpress.Web.Internal.JsonReader.ReadCore()
   at DevExpress.Web.Internal.JsonReader.Read(String jsonString)
   at DevExpress.Web.Internal.HtmlConvertor.FromJSON(String jsonString)
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExtensionValueProvidersFactory.GetValueProvider(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, String propertyName)
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.DevExpressEditorsBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.Internal.ContentControl`1.RenderInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.Internal.ContentControl`1.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.ExtensionBase.RenderControl(Control control)
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.ExtensionBase.RenderCallbackResultControl()
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.GridViewExtension.RenderCallbackResultControl()
   at DevExpress.Web.Mvc.ExtensionBase.RenderCallbackResult()
```

**Expected Result(s)**

I want all editing operations running fine for every detail grid states.

Any help and suggestions welcome, thanks in advance.